# How to reference to an array of products with unit-test in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: unit-testing, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

My shipment has an array of products, but I don't understand how to reference to do that array of product. I am trying to setup the unit test enviroment and need to make test data available.

shipment module

```
asset Shipment identified by shipmentId{
  o String shipmentId
  --> Product[] allProducts
  --> participant owner
}
```

and unit-test

```
const shipment = factory.newResource(namespace, 'Shipment', '001');
shipment.allProducts = factory.newRelationship(namespace, participant, /** what to do here */ )
```

or can I just pass an array of products like:

```
shipment.allProducts = products
```

The reason I am doubting this solution is because I need to use the factory newRelationship function. If you have a suggestion, that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you can copy the array with `shipment.allProducts = products.slice();`

Comment: And then the reference will stay intact?

Comment: If you use `.slice()` you clone the array in another variable, without it you only copy the reference to the original array (products). This means that if you don't use slice() and you modify `shipment.allProducts` the changes also affects the array `products`

Comment: But that is what I want, that is why I have a referenced it. So those assets should belong to the owner and he should be able to change it how he likes

Comment: @RiccardoBonesi the unit test says "model violation in Shipment#001 expected a Relationship"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I finally found the solution. My error message was:

> Instance org.trader.network.Shipment#001 has property allProducts with type org.trader.network.Product that is not derived from org.trader.network.Product[]

If you want to unit test and add some data to a referenced array type then do this:

> ```
>     shipment.allProducts= [factory.newRelationship(
>         namespace,
>         'Product',
>         product.$identifier
>     )];
> ```

Notice the brackets around the factory. I needed to make an array of relationships for product.

I only needed one product for my unit test, but if you want more, just add more relationships of a product in between the brackets.

I found the solution by looking at random github repository (source:[here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/fund-clearing-network/lib/clearing.js#L151))